# Get date as 'from date' and 'to date' from same column in table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a table that has a `timestamp` field 'changed_date'. I want to get the 'changed_date' as 'from_date' and 'to_date'. That is, for each row the 'from_date' value should come from the previous row 'changed_date' value.
For example:

[image]

I want to get the result grouped with 'project_id'. I want to get:

```
first row as:         null - 2015-07-02
second row as:  2015-07-02 - 2015-07-15
third row as:   2015-07-15 - 2015-07-28
```

Comment: update your question with sample data and output expected

Comment: What exactly is the difference between "for each row the previous date value" and "the previous row date value"?

Comment: Can you please shared with us sample data, could be help to understand your prob?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a window function to do this efficiently:

```
SELECT id, percentage, vat, service_tax, labor_welfare,
       daterange(lag(changed_date) OVER (PARTITION BY project_id ORDER BY changed_date)::date,
                  changed_date::date, '()') AS changed_date_range, project_id
FROM my_table
ORDER BY project_id, changed_date;
```

The output is a `daterange` which will look like '(2015-07-02, 2015-07-15)'. If you prefer a string format you can change the `daterange(...)` phrase into something like:

```
(to_char(lag(changed_date) OVER (PARTITION BY project_id ORDER BY changed_date), 'YYYY-MM-DD') ||
' - ' || to_char(changed_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS changed_date_range
```

or you can simply have two columns:

```
lag(changed_date) OVER (PARTITION BY project_id ORDER BY changed_date) AS date_from,
changed_date AS date_to
```

Comment: Any reason why you chose to use `date_range` over retrieving two columns?

Comment: @Patrick       Showing error "function date_range(timestamp without time zone, timestamp without time zone) does not exist"

Comment: @user1690835 It needs a `::date` cast. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do not undersatnd what you want..

Are you looking for something like

```
SELECT DATEADD(day,-1, changed_date) AS from_date, changed_date AS to_date FROM YOUR_TABLE;
```

Comment: If you do not understand the question, don't try an answer. Put comments asking for clarification.

Comment: There is no `dateadd()` function in Postgres.